# Bean of the repository defined in the dependency jar file is not creating when the main application starts

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, spring-data-couchbase

Hi I am new to Springboot,

I have 2 Springboot applications,

1. DSM
2. saveDataAPI

DSM is used to handle all the DB related interactions.

in DSM I have,

1. component class
2. Repository - uses CouchbaseRepository
3. Entity

component has a `save()` method which is used to save an entity to the to couchBase DB. DSM was build as a jar and it was included in saveDataAPI.
Added the component class details in the META-INF file in DSM so that saveDataAPI can access it.

[META_INF_File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbgeo.png)

I have injected the dependency of DSM's component class in saveDataAPI'2 service class to use the save function. I couldn't see any compilation error and also the maven build was success.

`@Autowired DSMController dsmController;`

But as I try to run saveDataAPI in eclispe, I am getting the below error.

Action:

`Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ums.sam.DSMModule.repo.DSMMRepository' in your configuration.`

DSMRepository is autowired to DSM's component class but as saveDataAPI  starts, it is unable to create the bean.

Can someone please suggest a way to resolve this.

Thank you.

Comment: sounds like a classic `@ComponentScan` problem - by default SpringBoot will only scan packages directly under where it has been defined and obviously not scan packages in depedencies that have different package name from yours

Comment: I have modified the details, could you please have a look. @JAsgarov

Comment: you either need to point to the package where `DSMMRepository` is defined OR define `DSMMRepository` as Bean again in your application. In any case you need to read a simple tutorial / documentation on Spring

Comment: Can you provide a link to your repo so I can look into it?